# Code coverage using lcov+gtest only reports on the coverage of the unit test cpp file, not the files of the library being tested

Tags: c++, cmake, lcov

I am trying to implement a small example on how to use google test and lcov so I can see how my testing of the code is doing. [Here](https://github.com/apalomer/unit_test_coverage) is my example repository.

My project has the following file tree:

```
unit_test_coverage/
  |--CMakeLists.txt
  |--.gitignore
  |--src/
       |--CMakeLists.txt
       |--foo.h
       |--foo.cpp
       |--test/
            |--CMakeLists.txt
            |--unit_test.cpp
```

The library is just one class with two methods and a member:

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(const double& value);

  double times(const double& value) const;

  bool isPositive() const;

private:
  double m_value;
};

#endif  // FOO_H_
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo::Foo(const double& value) : m_value(value){};

double Foo::times(const double& value) const
{
  return m_value * value;
}

bool Foo::isPositive() const
{
  return m_value > 0;
}
```

and the unit test only tests one of the methods of the class:

**unit_test.cpp**

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "../foo.h"

TEST(Foo, times)
{
  EXPECT_EQ(Foo(4).times(4), 16);
}
```

In the `CMakeLists.txt` of the root folder, I have added a custom target to run the test and generate the coverage report:

```
add_custom_target(run_tests
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_BIN}/unit_test
  COMMAND lcov --capture --directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} --output-file gtest_demo.info --test-name gtest_demo --no-external
  COMMAND genhtml gtest_demo.info --output-directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/coverage_report --title "Code coverage report" --show-details --legend
)
```

When I run `make run_tests` a coverage report is generated:
[image]

[image]

However, the report does not include the coverage of the files `foo.h` and `foo.cpp`, which is the opposite of what I want, as I want to check whether or not the `Foo` class is properly tested and covered. How can I incorporate the coverage of the class `Foo` (files `foo.h` and `foo.cpp`)?

Comment: You add profile options only for the test: https://github.com/apalomer/unit_test_coverage/blob/master/src/test/CMakeLists.txt#L47. What else do you expect?

Comment: My bad, I did not read the documentation, which makes it crystal clear that the effect of [`add_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) only affectes the current directory and childs, but not parents.

Comment: [OT]: for `EXPECT_EQ`, it is expected first normally (so error message is correct in case of failure).

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't understand your comment. Can you explain it a bit better? I guess I am doing something wrong but cannot figure out what! Thanks!!

Comment: I meant it should be: `EXPECT_EQ(16, Foo(4).times(4));`. Not a big deal with wrong order, just the error message (for failed test) which might be a little "confusing".